# Implementing interface in golang gives method has pointer receiver

Tags: go

am working in Golang, am trying to use interfaces to agroup a set of structs that are using a similar method. Briefly I have this:

```
type Person interface {
    BasicInfo() MemberBasicInfo
}

type MemberBasicInfo struct {
    ID                         uint       
    MemberFirstName            string     
    MemberNickname             string     
    MemberEmail                string    
}
```

Then, the structs that should work as interfaces:

```
func (member *Member) BasicInfo() MemberBasicInfo{
    return MemberBasicInfo{
        ID: member.ID,
        ...other mapping here...
    }
}

func (user *User) BasicInfo() MemberBasicInfo{
    return MemberBasicInfo{
        ID: uint(user.ID),
        ...other mapping here...
    }
}

cannot use memberData (type Member) as type Member.Person in return argument: Member does not implement Person (BasicInfo method has pointer receiver)
cannot use memberData (type User) as type Person in return argument: User does not implement Person (BasicInfo method has pointer receiver)
```

What am I missing? or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the code which generates this compiler message?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If your interface is declared like this:

```
type Person interface {
    BasicInfo() MemberBasicInfo
}
```

Then any type that implements a `BasicInfo() MemberBasicInfo` will fulfil the interface.

In your case, you then created this method:

```
func (member *Member) BasicInfo() MemberBasicInfo
```

That means that the type `*Member` fulfils the interface.

But.. note the `*` there. `Member` does not implement the interface, it is `*Member` who does.

So when trying to assign a type to an interface variable, make sure to use a pointer and not a direct value.

This should work:

```
var p Person
p = &Member{}
```

But this will not:

```
var p Person
p = Member{}
```

Comment: Just wanna say this is the clearest and simplest explanation of "why" this error occurs generally that I've seen.

Answer (score 5):

A pointer receiver requires you to assign pointers of a concrete class to variables of the interface type.

```
func usage() {
    var x Person

    // Notice the ampersand '&'
    x = &Member{}

    x.BasicInfo()
}
```